# How do I make a loop to look for and delete rows with specific text from a spreadsheet with varied ranges?

Tags: vba, loops

How do I create a script in VBA to copy rows beginning with text composed of a variable amount of spaces followed by a numerical value?

1. The rows with spaces followed by a numerical value can vary in where
   they are in the spreadsheet.
2. I also need to apply a similar loop, I believe, to look copy rows with the text of spaces followed by the word "cash". These spaces can also vary in amount as well as where this row is in the spreadsheet.
3. I then want to paste all these rows on a new sheet and split text to
   column.

I am unsure how to address the unknown amount of spaces that could appear before the integer. It will always be a whole number if I could define the `cell.value` to look for integers/numbers/values). I will apply this to text too, just don't know how to address the number of spaces before these rows. I could maybe incorporate a trim before splitting the list of numbers, but again not sure how to incorporate this after `cell.value`.

I have:

```
Sub Test()

If Cell.Value = _________ Then
    matchRow = Cell.Row
    Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
    Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets(4).Select
    ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets(4).Select
   End If
Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Do you have any code attempts to share? If not, have you tried researching how to incorporate loops in VBA? Plenty of resources to help get you started

Comment: But I cannot enter code with ______ representative of the unknown amount of spaces before values. Basically I have a spreadsheet with data in column B that are all whole numbers, but there is a varying amount of spaces before each number beginning that row. I could trim the column, then make the loop search for anything that is a "number", but i don't know how to define this and code properly

Comment: Use Trim to remove the spaces.

Comment: Add some sample data to your question. Show us some expected ranges of inputs and which inputs are of interest and why

Comment: Something like this is probably what you want: `If IsNumeric(Trim(.Cells(i, 1).Value)) Then`

Comment: Thank you for your quick responsiveness.I can't seem to attach my file. I can either trim all the columns in my range B that I want to copy all number values from (170,000, 150,000, 130,000 for example), but DO NOT want to include a value that includes numbers with a letter (170,000M) for example. OR I can loop to look for numbers followed by spaces. The inputs are on Sheet 1 Range: "B" and I want to post in column "A" on Sheet 4.

Comment: Warcupine's comment is what you're looking for. IsNumeric is how you test if a value can be used as a number. If there was an "M" at the end, IsNumeric would return false.

Comment: Where in the code do i insert that line of code from Warcupine, is it instead of "If Cell.Value = _________ Then"? Or elsewhere? Just making sure that the rest of my code works taking into consideration how to apply Warcupines code line. Seperately, is there a way to be able to find a string that was numeric ending with a letter?

Comment: Please assist in inserting warcupines code into my macro. How could i find the row item starting with a number followed by an "m" with no space in between? It'd be like a string of numbers followed by M.